# Google Reader public API?

Tags: web-services

Is there any way to access information on the feeds that Google Reader knows about without having to authenticate?

I do not wish to do anything specific to a Google Reader account, I just want some data about a given RSS feed such as post history/frequency, and am hoping that there is a way to get this from Google Reader, since it will probably have the largest collection of feeds and data. The only ways I can find to get this data is after authenticating and obtaining an SID, token, etc, but this will be unnecessary for my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for "the largest collection of feeds and data", you should take a look at the [Google Feeds API](http://code.google.com/apis/feed/).  All the RSS feeds that the Google search engine has ever seen at your fingertips, and served from Google's index instead of from the originating site. The feeds api doesn't provide prepackaged statistics about post frequency, but it does provide post history data so you can make your own calculations.

The Google Feeds API does require an API key, but it's not hard to get or to use.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are seeking, but you can access all the feed items of a folder through URLs like this:
http://www.google.com/reader/shared/user/[user_id]/label/[folder_name]

Here's a concrete example:
http://www.google.com/reader/shared/user/13577231804381328821/label/googlers

Taken from here, where you can read more about this:
http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/07/export-feeds-from-google-reader-folder.html